# jQuery toggle() with no animation but complete function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle an element's visibility without animation, but with a complete function so that I change the text of the link initiating the toggle.

```
jQuery('.toggle_tags').click(function(){
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('#taglist').toggle({complete: function() {
        if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            elem.text('(Hide Tags)');
        } else {
            elem.text('(View Tags)');
        }
    },});
    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately this is still triggering animation. Without ANY params, toggle doesn't animate but even either by passing just a function or the complete function verbosely (as above), I still get animation.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point is. What does `this` point to inside the toggle parameter, and why can't you refer to it outside the toggle?

Comment: The problem is that `toggle`'s default `duration` parameter is `400`.

Comment: @Juhana my understanding was it was asynchronous and that not using the complete function might have meant `is visible` test would have been unreliable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use a `complete` function.

Without parameters, `.toggle()` will operate synchronously, meaning that you can just test what it did in the next statement, knowing that it will already have finished, you could use:

```
jQuery('#taglist').toggle();
if (jQuery('#taglist').is(':visible')) {
    elem.text('(Hide Tags)');
} else {
    elem.text('(View Tags)');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware it was synchronous without params. Why offer a complete callback then?

Comment: @deed02392 For the cases when you *do* have animation.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `duration: 0` to the options object. More info [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: I considered this but it didn't seem elegant enough for jQuery. ;-)

Comment: According to the docs, this is essentially what setting `jQuery.fx.off = true` does, so it seems to me this is quite jQuery-appropriate.