# Use jQuery show() with complete function and no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, backbone.js

This question is in addition to [jQuery toggle() with no animation...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973961/jquery-toggle-with-no-animation-but-complete-function)

In order to avoid animation on `show` of element, I'm trying to replace below 2 lines

```
var that = this;
this.$el.show("fast", null, function(){that.updatePosition()});
```

with following,

```
this.$el.show();    
this.updatePosition();
```

Is it possible that function `updatePosition` will be called before current element becomes `visible`? If yes then what is the workaround solution i should try to avoid animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass duration as **`0`** as a first argument in `jQueryElement.show`. The `callback` function will be invoked after `0` duration.

```
$(this).show(0, function() {
  //callback function
});
```

Comment: @RayonDabre You had a typo in your code: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30371837/revisions

Comment: pretty reasonable answer. But i would also like to know whether the solution suggested in question can give some problem.

Comment: @Arshad Rehmani, default duration for .show() is 400ms so the method you have called after .show() method will be executed before the show() complete event. you can go with .css('display','none') instead of show() if you are not looking for animation..